# Postman - automating PATCH requests for Listings Items API with JSON data

Tags: postman, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to automate PATCH requests with the Listings Items API using Postman. I want to send a payload to a destination and repeat the process for dozens of destinations; the payloads are all slightly different but the structure is the same.

The urls would be something like this: `https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/XXXXX/{{sku}}?marketplaceIds=ATVPDKIKX0DER`

The JSON payload structure would look like this:

```
{
  "productType": "SHOES",
  "patches": [
    {
      "op": "replace",
      "path": "/attributes/item_name",
      "value": [
        {
          "value": "Updated item name",
          "language_tag": "en_US",
          "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to automate GET requests but am not sure how to do this with PATCH requests when sending payloads to different destinations.